# How to remove ground detections of an ultrasonic sensor place in the front bumper of car?

Tags: electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, sensors, signal-processing

I am working on a project to fuse the sensor information of 4 ultrasonic sensors place on the front of a car in the bumpers. The detections from the sensor would be generated not only from the obstacles but also from the ground.

Is there a way I could filter or differentiate the points being detected from the ground and the points being detected from an obstacle?

Also, apart from the usual case where ultrasonic gives the reading of the nearest object to the sensor, the ultrasonic sensor can give information from multiple points in the scene.

Comment: "*Is there a way I could filter or differentiate the points being detected from the ground and the points being detected from an obstacle?*" No. Filtering would be done by shaping the ultrasonic beam emitted from the sensor to avoid it hitting the ground.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I could filter or differentiate the points being detected from the ground and the points being detected from an obstacle?

As @Transistor said, No. You have to check the sensor profile and install it to avoid hitting the ground (or choose a sensor with a profile that fit your application). For example, below is the Caracteristic Response Curve of an analog ultrasonic sensor from Pepperl-Fuch:

[image]

> Also, apart from the usual case where ultrasonic gives the reading of the nearest object to the sensor, the ultrasonic sensor can give information from multiple points in the scene.

Considering a single fixed sensor, No. The sensor will always give you a single response on the return of the ultrasonic pulse (being an analogue or binary response depending on the type of sensor), as the pulse is pointed in the same direction, you will always have a single piece of information. The only way would be to move the sensor in time, emulating something like a 2D Radar (there are some [arduino projects](https://techatronic.com/radar-using-arduino-ultrasonic-sensor/) that can help you with some ideas).